# Webforms response.redirect returns correct URL and reloads same page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, redirect, webforms

I do some execution when a button is pressed on my webform, inserting an item into my db and storing some info into the session. At the end of that execution the form is supposed to redirect to the next page, but instead it reloads the same page with the URL altered. I have tried to change it from Response.Redirect("URL") to Server.TransferRequest and it still does the same thing. Code is as follows:

```
protected void CheckoutConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        //some irrelevant code
        using (ShoppingCartActions usersShoppingCart = new ShoppingCartActions())
        {
            placedOrder.totalPrice = usersShoppingCart.GetTotal();
            _db.Orders.Add(placedOrder);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            List<CartItem> itemsInCart = usersShoppingCart.GetCartItems();
            //creating corresponding OrderProducts for each product in this order
            foreach (CartItem o in itemsInCart)
            {
                Orderproducts myOrderProduct = new Orderproducts();
                myOrderProduct.ProductID = o.ProductId;
                myOrderProduct.OrderID = placedOrder.OrderID;
                myOrderProduct.quantity = o.Quantity;
                _db.OrderProducts.Add(myOrderProduct);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                Session.Clear();
                Session["CustomerName"] = customer.CustomerName;
                Session["orderID"] = placedOrder.OrderID;
                Session["orderStatus"] = placedOrder.OrderStatus;
                Session["Address"] = customer.CustomerName + "\r\n" + customer.Address + "\r\n" + customer.City + "\r\n" + customer.Country;
            }
        }

        Server.TransferRequest("Checkout/finishedCheckout.aspx");
```

Comment: `Response.Redirect("PageName.aspx")` should work fine!

Comment: Yeah, it should. It is working on all the other pages that redirect, but on this page it does not, it simply redirects to the same page and changes the URL to the correct URL.

Comment: Change it to `Response.Redirect` and set a breakpoint in your code, see if that line is reached. Also, watch the network traffic on the browser.

Comment: try using the absolute page name i.e. `Response.Redirect("finishedCheckout.aspx")` rather than `Response.Redirect("Checkout/finishedCheckout.aspx")`?

Comment: @mason I did the breakpoint and it does reach it, how do I check the network traffic?

Comment: You look at the network tab of your browser's development tools, usually brought up by pressing F12. My guess is that you'll see it redirects to the page you want to go to, and then some logic on that page is causing it to redirect back.

Comment: @ObiEff : press `Ctlr+Shift+I` if you are using Google Chrome!

Comment: Turns out there is a null reference exception occurring which is halting the redirect for some reason this is giving me the exception HttpContext.Current.Session["CartId"] == null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was an null reference exception which occurred in the Page_PreRender within the master page. Due to the exception the redirect would not finish and the same page would just reload.